# Why does htop display nothing?

Tags: htop

My Ubuntu `htop` command does not display anything, like this:

[image: htop displays nothing]

Is there any problem with this command? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try restarting?

Comment: Does `top` works??

Comment: To check if it's a display problem, try redirecting output into a file, `htop > test.dat`. Does that file contain data? If yes, you have a display problem.

Comment: I did restart the computer, and the top command works fine. However, htop doesn't work. And I use htop>test.dat to redirecting output into a file,but I still got little information, I even tried to reinstall htop, but still cannot fix the problem. So I am still confused....

Comment: Have you tried running `htop` with sudo just to make sure it's not a permissions issue?

Comment: If it isn't permissions, you could try removing the htop configuration file (`~/.config/htop/htoprc`)

Answer (score -1):

I think you should follow instructions list on GitHub homepage. Maybe your `ncurses` library is not correct and incompatible. [enter link description here](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html)

The `static` compilation maybe useful for same error. I think the cause of this error is lack of or wrong dynamical link of `ncurses`

Comment: Add extra details to your answer, **not** in the comments.